# Unable to understand proof of Fibonacci number

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

This [page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/) - in the method 6, I am unable to get this line and after it.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are not view-able to some.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I will keep in mind from now. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They consider the product
$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle A_n}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}F_{m+1}&F_m\\F_m&F_{m-1}\end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle A_m}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}F_{m+n+1}&F_{m+n}\\F_{m+n}&F_{m+n-1}\end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle A_{m+n}}$$
and they identify the lower right terms.